# Get the sum of duplicate values in an array but only if they are side by side

Tags: arrays, duplicates

I have an array like this:

```
var myArray =  [[1,1,1,2,3,3,1,3]];
```

And I wanted to get the sum of the duplicate value that are side by side.
So something like this: `[3,1,2,1,1]`

I tried it with this code but it kind of display each sum while on the for loop.

```
var data=1;
var sum = [];
for (i=0; i < myArray.length;i++){
    for (x=0; x < myArray[i].length;x++){
        if (myArray[i][x] == myArray[i][x-1]){
            data++;
        }else{
            data=1;
        }
        sum.push(data);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

But I get this instead: `[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]`
Can anybody please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is almost there.

- I would start by comparing from `x=1` to avoid getting out of bounds with the comparison: `myArray[i][x] == myArray[i][x-1]`.
- `sum.push(data)` can be moved inside the `else` statement, because we want to push, only after we find a different number.
- Finally, we need to remember to push the last value of `data` in the `sum` array.

```js
var data=1;
var sum = [];
for (i=0; i < myArray.length;i++){
    for (x=1; x < myArray[i].length;x++){
        if (myArray[i][x] == myArray[i][x-1]){
            data++;
        }else{
            sum.push(data);
            data=1;
        }
    }
    sum.push(data);
    console.log(sum);
}
```